# Generate barcode and save image file

Tags: php, barcode

I am generating one barcode image but I am not able to save that file in specific folder. I Just want to generate the image and save that image to folder without display in folder.
Below i my code.

**Class File: barcode.php**

```
<?php
    class barcode {

        function __construct() {

        }

        public function generateBarcode($text = '', $size = '', $orientation = '', $code_type = '', $filepath) {
            $text = (isset($text) ? $text : "0");
            $size = (isset($size) ? $size : "20");
            $orientation = (isset($orientation) ? $orientation : "horizontal");
            $code_type = (isset($code_type) ? $code_type : "code128");
            $code_string = "";

            // Translate the $text into barcode the correct $code_type
            if (strtolower($code_type) == "code128") {
                $chksum = 104;
                // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
                $code_array = array(" " => "212222", "!" => "222122", "\"" => "222221", "#" => "121223", "$" => "121322", "%" => "131222", "&" => "122213", "'" => "122312", "(" => "132212", ")" => "221213", "*" => "221312", "+" => "231212", "," => "112232", "-" => "122132", "." => "122231", "/" => "113222", "0" => "123122", "1" => "123221", "2" => "223211", "3" => "221132", "4" => "221231", "5" => "213212", "6" => "223112", "7" => "312131", "8" => "311222", "9" => "321122", ":" => "321221", ";" => "312212", "<" => "322112", "=" => "322211", ">" => "212123", "?" => "212321", "@" => "232121", "A" => "111323", "B" => "131123", "C" => "131321", "D" => "112313", "E" => "132113", "F" => "132311", "G" => "211313", "H" => "231113", "I" => "231311", "J" => "112133", "K" => "112331", "L" => "132131", "M" => "113123", "N" => "113321", "O" => "133121", "P" => "313121", "Q" => "211331", "R" => "231131", "S" => "213113", "T" => "213311", "U" => "213131", "V" => "311123", "W" => "311321", "X" => "331121", "Y" => "312113", "Z" => "312311", "[" => "332111", "\\" => "314111", "]" => "221411", "^" => "431111", "_" => "111224", "\`" => "111422", "a" => "121124", "b" => "121421", "c" => "141122", "d" => "141221", "e" => "112214", "f" => "112412", "g" => "122114", "h" => "122411", "i" => "142112", "j" => "142211", "k" => "241211", "l" => "221114", "m" => "413111", "n" => "241112", "o" => "134111", "p" => "111242", "q" => "121142", "r" => "121241", "s" => "114212", "t" => "124112", "u" => "124211", "v" => "411212", "w" => "421112", "x" => "421211", "y" => "212141", "z" => "214121", "{" => "412121", "|" => "111143", "}" => "111341", "~" => "131141", "DEL" => "114113", "FNC 3" => "114311", "FNC 2" => "411113", "SHIFT" => "411311", "CODE C" => "113141", "FNC 4" => "114131", "CODE A" => "311141", "FNC 1" => "411131", "Start A" => "211412", "Start B" => "211214", "Start C" => "211232", "Stop" => "2331112");
                $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
                $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
                for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++) {
                    $activeKey = substr($text, ($X - 1), 1);
                    $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
                    $chksum = ($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
                }
                $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

                $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";
            } elseif (strtolower($code_type) == "code39") {
                $code_array = array("0" => "111221211", "1" => "211211112", "2" => "112211112", "3" => "212211111", "4" => "111221112", "5" => "211221111", "6" => "112221111", "7" => "111211212", "8" => "211211211", "9" => "112211211", "A" => "211112112", "B" => "112112112", "C" => "212112111", "D" => "111122112", "E" => "211122111", "F" => "112122111", "G" => "111112212", "H" => "211112211", "I" => "112112211", "J" => "111122211", "K" => "211111122", "L" => "112111122", "M" => "212111121", "N" => "111121122", "O" => "211121121", "P" => "112121121", "Q" => "111111222", "R" => "211111221", "S" => "112111221", "T" => "111121221", "U" => "221111112", "V" => "122111112", "W" => "222111111", "X" => "121121112", "Y" => "221121111", "Z" => "122121111", "-" => "121111212", "." => "221111211", " " => "122111211", "$" => "121212111", "/" => "121211121", "+" => "121112121", "%" => "111212121", "*" => "121121211");

                // Convert to uppercase
                $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

                for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($upper_text); $X++) {
                    $code_string .= $code_array[substr($upper_text, ($X - 1), 1)] . "1";
                }

                $code_string = "1211212111" . $code_string . "121121211";
            } elseif (strtolower($code_type) == "code25") {
                $code_array1 = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");
                $code_array2 = array("3-1-1-1-3", "1-3-1-1-3", "3-3-1-1-1", "1-1-3-1-3", "3-1-3-1-1", "1-3-3-1-1", "1-1-1-3-3", "3-1-1-3-1", "1-3-1-3-1", "1-1-3-3-1");

                for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++) {
                    for ($Y = 0; $Y < count($code_array1); $Y++) {
                        if (substr($text, ($X - 1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y])
                            $temp[$X] = $code_array2[$Y];
                    }
                }

                for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X+=2) {
                    if (isset($temp[$X]) && isset($temp[($X + 1)])) {
                        $temp1 = explode("-", $temp[$X]);
                        $temp2 = explode("-", $temp[($X + 1)]);
                        for ($Y = 0; $Y < count($temp1); $Y++)
                            $code_string .= $temp1[$Y] . $temp2[$Y];
                    }
                }

                $code_string = "1111" . $code_string . "311";
            } elseif (strtolower($code_type) == "codabar") {
                $code_array1 = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "$", ":", "/", ".", "+", "A", "B", "C", "D");
                $code_array2 = array("1111221", "1112112", "2211111", "1121121", "2111121", "1211112", "1211211", "1221111", "2112111", "1111122", "1112211", "1122111", "2111212", "2121112", "2121211", "1121212", "1122121", "1212112", "1112122", "1112221");

                // Convert to uppercase
                $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

                for ($X = 1; $X <= strlen($upper_text); $X++) {
                    for ($Y = 0; $Y < count($code_array1); $Y++) {
                        if (substr($upper_text, ($X - 1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y])
                            $code_string .= $code_array2[$Y] . "1";
                    }
                }
                $code_string = "11221211" . $code_string . "1122121";
            }

            // Pad the edges of the barcode
            $code_length = 20;
            for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($code_string); $i++)
                $code_length = $code_length + (integer) (substr($code_string, ($i - 1), 1));

            if (strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal") {
                $img_width = $code_length;
                $img_height = $size;
            } else {
                $img_width = $size;
                $img_height = $code_length;
            }

            $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
            $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
            $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

            imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

            $location = 10;
            for ($position = 1; $position <= strlen($code_string); $position++) {
                $cur_size = $location + ( substr($code_string, ($position - 1), 1) );
                if (strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal")
                    imagefilledrectangle($image, $location, 0, $cur_size, $img_height, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black));
                else
                    imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, $location, $img_width, $cur_size, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black));
                $location = $cur_size;
            }

            // Draw barcode to the screen
            header('Content-type: image/png');
            imagepng($image,'one.png');
            imagedestroy($image);
        }

    }
?>
```

**Called method:**

```
    <?php
    include('barcode.php');
    $barObj = new barcode();
    $barObj->generateBarcode('Praveen','vertical','40','C128','one.png');
?>
```

I am getting error like "The image “http://example.com/index.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: giving error like "The image “http://localhost/tcpdf_min/mybarcode/index.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."

Answer (score 0):

You won't need `header('Content-type: image/png');` when you want to save the image to a file. Also, putting that line in your script sets the content type to PNG Image and will cause issues viewing the whole page for the users, if you are going to write other stuff in your page.

By the way, as my personal experience, including files to work with GD is not a good way. Try generating the image using CURL instead.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to target folder? You are going to save the image inside your php file's folder right?

Answer (score 0):

As @amsonline has mentioned, the header line there is making it tricky to see what is going on. Below is a technique I've found is helpful. When you're ready to make this write to the browser, you can change the `imagepng` call to `imagepng($image)` and that will write the png data directly.

When you get a broken image like this script is going to show in a browser, if you look at the data you're getting back, it's usually very helpful. In chrome, you can use the developer tools to do this easily. However, I find it's easier to do this with linux in some situations.

So, in this case, I took a wager that there wouldn't be a bunch of garbage echoed to my screen; that was a good wager in this case.

```
$ curl http://testserver.example.com/barcode.php

Warning: imagecreate() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in /var/www/lighttpd/barcode.php on line 91

Warning: imagecolorallocate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/lighttpd/barcode.php on line 92

Warning: imagecolorallocate() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/lighttpd/barcode.php on line 93

Warning: imagefill() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/lighttpd/barcode.php on line 95

Warning: imagepng() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/lighttpd/barcode.php on line 109

Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/lighttpd/barcode.php on line 110
```

Now that we can see a list of errors, it's time to go through them, one by one and work from there. The easiest way to sort through some of these is going to be some echos and whatnot, that first error is really telling you that "we're not getting what we expect". I'll leave the full debugging process as an exercise for ya.

Once you think it might output an image, you can always pipe the curl call through xxd to prevent from garbling your terminal. Once you start seeing binary, the browser will become your next favorite debugging tool.